# New array declaration in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, what is the difference between:

```
new_array = old_array
```

and

```
new_array = Array.new(old_array)
```

Comment: `Object.new` does not take an argument, maybe you should pick a class that does, like `String` or `Array`.

Comment: @stefan .. Thanks, I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

The first one is assignment, and will not create a new object. The second one is invalid (under default definition of `Object`), and will raise an argument error.

Comment: Just edited my question. what happens in case we use an Array or String instead of Object?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
old_arr = [1,2,3]              #=> [1, 2, 3] 
old_arr.object_id              #=> 70142672048160 

new_arr = old_arr              #=> [1, 2, 3] 
new_arr.object_id              #=> 70142672048160 

newer_arr = Array.new(old_arr) #=> [1, 2, 3] 
newer_arr.object_id            #=> 70142675883800
```

So you see the local variables `old_arr` and `new_arr` hold the same array object. By contrast, the variable `newer_arr` holds a different array object.

Now try this:

```
old_arr[0] = 'X'               #=> "X" 
old_arr                        #=> ["X", 2, 3]
```

then

```
new_arr                        #=> ["X", 2, 3] 
newer_arr                      #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

`newer_arr` points to what is called a "shallow copy" of `old_arr`. To see what this means, consider another example:

```
old_arr = [1,2,[3,4]]          #=> [1, 2, [3, 4]] 
new_arr = old_arr              #=> [1, 2, [3, 4]] 
newer_arr = Array.new(old_arr) #=> [1, 2, [3, 4]] 

old_arr[0] = 'X'               #=> "X"
old_arr[2][0] = 'Y'            #=> "Y"
old_arr                        #=> ["X", 2, ["Y", 4]] 
new_arr                        #=> ["X", 2, ["Y", 4]] 
newer_arr                      #=> [1, 2, ["Y", 4]]
```

As before, `newer_arr[0]` has not been modified, and `newer_arr[2]` contains the same object as it did previously, but that object has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

"what happens in case we use an Array or String instead of Object?"

That depends on the class definition itself, so you should look at the documentation.
Basically, #new method creates a new object and then calls "initialize" method with parameters passed to it.

To answer your question:
Array.new method copies the array passed to it (actually, as i said before: it passes that array to initialize method, which copies it).
Same happens with String.

The easiest way to know such things is actually repl.
In irb execute following lines, one by one:

```
a = ":)"
b = a
a[1] = '('
puts a
puts b


a = ":)"
b = String.new(a)
a[1] = '('
puts a
puts b


a = [1,2,3]
b = a
a[1] = 10
puts a
puts b


a = [1,2,3]
b = Array.new(a)
a[1] = 10
puts a
puts b
```